# date-fns - how to convert date and hr with minute to iso format?

Tags: date-fns

I am getting a value as `15/07/2019, 18 : 07` - it contains date and hr with minute.
But I would require to send backend as ISO format. how to do with `date-fns` framewroks? any one help me?

here is the format I am looking for:

`2019-07-19T07:37:06.413Z`

any one help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

To obtain the ISO8601 string representation of a date you don't need `date-fns`. You can simply use the [`Date.toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method. For example:

```
> new Date().toISOString()
'2019-09-02T11:54:53.506Z'
```

Or if you need to parse the date (`date-fns` objects have all the methods from `Date`):

```
> import { parse } from 'date-fns'
> parse('15/07/2019 18:07', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm', new Date()).toISOString()
'2019-07-15T17:07:00.000Z'
```

Note that the parsed date is assumed to be in the local time zone.

Comment: This helped. At first, I struggled a bit but i later got it to work in `addBusinessDays` like this : `addBusinessDays(parseISO(arg.toISOString()), 5)` where `arg` was the date of interest. @Pedro Romano